# Returning mixed safe & unsafe content from handlebars helper

Tags: handlebars.js

Say I've got this helper, but I don't want to trust the value of `name` as it's user generated content:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('button', function(name) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    "<button>" + name + "</button>"
  );
});
```

Is it possible to tell handlebars that only part of the string should be safe?

Eg. (this doesn't work, but you get the idea):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('button', function(name) {
  return [
    new Handlebars.SafeString("<button>"), 
    name,
    new Handlebars.SafeString("</button>")
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can escape the unsafe part, making the whole string safe, as opposed to marking parts as unsafe:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('button', function(name) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    "<button>" + Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(name) + "</button>"
  );
});
```